# Yahoo OAuth library in java?

Tags: java, oauth, yahoo

Anybody knows any good yahoo oauth library in java?.

Using that library, i should fetch yahoo mails using oauth authentication.

Thanks
Aravind S

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). Very simple API and works great.

On a side note, be aware that **Yahoo expires their auth token after 60 minutes** so you need to refresh it periodically. Alas, Yahoo is the only oauth provider that I am aware of that expires their token and so **scribe and signpost and other oauth APIs don't implement a "refresh token"** mechanism. From my research, everyone that uses the APIs has implemented their own custom refresh method, myself included. I and others have approached the scribe author about integrating the refresh token feature but he has no interest.

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing with oauth-signpost recently for interacting with Yahoo YQL...although I haven't found a good 2-legged example.

http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

Comment: I am trying to use http://github.com/ramiyer/ymailtables which  internally uses oauth signpost and httpclient.
I am unable to run on app engine because httpclient uses some https url connection class from jdk which is black listed by GAE. 
I am thinking to change source code of sign-post or httpclient to run in GAE.

BTW, Yahoo oauth documentation is very poor.  :)